# Implementing double hashing for integers that can be negative

Tags: java, c++, hash, double-hashing

I am implementing a hash class for integers using the double hashing method. The input will be random integers that can be either positive or negative.

My question is how will I compute the hash value of negative integers?

This is the method:

```
hash function 1 h: h(k) = k mod (p)
hash function 2 s(k)= p –2 – (k mod(p-2))
p = table size, k = key
```

After computing h(k), if there is no collision, it will be inserted in its position. If there is collision, I will compute (h(k) + s(k)) mod p and will store the key in the resulting value of the computation.

So my question is if the key is a negative integer, should I take its absolute value (make it positive) before hashing it? Or is there any other method?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Princeton Algorithms website](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/):

> Q: What's wrong with using (s.hashCode() % M) or Math.abs(s.hashCode()) % M to hash to a value between 0 and M-1?
>
> A: The % operator returns a non-positive integer if its first argument is negative, and this would create an array index out-of-bounds error. Surprisingly, the absolute value function can even return a negative integer. This happens if its argument is Integer.MIN_VALUE because the resulting positive integer cannot be represented using a 32-bit two's complement integer. This kind of bug would be excruciatingly difficult to track down because it would only occur one time in 4 billion! [ The String hash code of "polygenelubricants" is -2^31. ]

Java computes an index from a hashcode [as follows](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.hash%28int%29):

```
 static int indexFor(int hashcode, int length) {
     return hashcode & (length-1);
 }
```

Comment: So can I just take the absolute value of negative inputs and find their hash value?

Comment: The bottom line of the link I added is that it'll be very rare to receive a negative hash value that will have a negative absolute value, but it happens, and can cause bad bugs that'll be very hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you hash with funtion 1 first and then place result in function 2 the result will allways be a positive number.

In function 2

```
If k > 0 => 0 < (k mod (p - 2)) < p - 2
```

So function 2 returns a positive value

```
If k < 0 => (k mod (p - 2)) < 0
```

Then `-(k mod (p - 2)) > 0`

So function 2 returns a positive value

In either case the double hashing will return a positive value from function 2 no matter if the input is positive or negative.

Comment: I noticed that when the input is negative, it crashes the program as function 1 returns a negative result. When this is checked with hash table for collision, it causes the program to crash. For example HashTable[hash] assuming 'hash' is the result of function 1 so when it is negative, it will crash without computing function 2.

Comment: Ok, I though you called function 2 directly after function 1 in the manner of hash = function2(function1(k)); Then abs of k would be one way to solve it.